# What does "rm -rf" do?

Tags: rm

I have seen the command rm -r, rm -f, and rm. I was wondering what does rm -rf do, I have looked all over and can't seem to find the answer

Comment: Correct answer below by Moonpoint.... https://linux.die.net/man/1/rm, read, test, and accept when you get a chance. 
When you get a moment, look over the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour). Check out ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) when you get a chance as well.

Answer (score 4):

The [rm command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rm_%28Unix%29) removes files. The -r option will perform a recursive removal and the `-f` option will remove files without prompting you to confirm that you wish to have them removed, even if you would otherwise be prompted as to whether you wish to remove them due to the files permissions. E.g., if you type `rm -rf somedirectory`, the command will remove all files and subdirectories beneath the directory named somedirectory as well as that directory itself. You need to be careful when using the `-r` and `-f` options else you may remove far more than you intended. You can see information on its usage by typing `man rm` in a [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_%28macOS%29) window, which will display the [man page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) for the command.

Answer (score 0):

It deletes things ... rm is remove ... so don't use it especially if you are in the root directory, well make sure you are careful : a backup is good, it's very useful when used correctly...

Link to explanation : https://www.computerhope.com/unix/urm.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should use "command --help" to get more info about any command, where command in this case is rm

eg. rm --help

`$ rm --help
Usage: rm [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Remove (unlink) the FILE(s).`

-f, --force           ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
  -i                    prompt before every removal
  -I                    prompt once before removing more than three files, or
                          when removing recursively; less intrusive than -i,
                          while still giving protection against most mistakes
      --interactive[=WHEN]  prompt according to WHEN: never, once (-I), or
                          always (-i); without WHEN, prompt always
      --one-file-system  when removing a hierarchy recursively, skip any
                          directory that is on a file system different from
                          that of the corresponding command line argument
      --no-preserve-root  do not treat '/' specially
      --preserve-root   do not remove '/' (default)
  -r, -R, --recursive   remove directories and their contents recursively
  -d, --dir             remove empty directories
  -v, --verbose         explain what is being done
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

By default, rm does not remove directories.  Use the --recursive (-r or -R)
option to remove each listed directory, too, along with all of its contents.

To remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo',
use one of these commands:
  rm -- -foo

rm ./-foo

Note that if you use rm to remove a file, it might be possible to recover
some of its contents, given sufficient expertise and/or time.  For greater
assurance that the contents are truly unrecoverable, consider using shred.

GNU coreutils online help: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/
Full documentation at: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/rm
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) rm invocation'